# Python sub process not gets kill when main process killed using "kill -9" command

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, kill-process, manual

> "main.py" will trigger sub process of another python (test.py). When I
>   kill main.py process id using "kill -9 main.py pid", sub process
>   still running in background. Help me with full code how to tackle
>   this.

**main.py**

`try:
    p=subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'test.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode != 0: 
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode,args)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    print("Subprocess failed")
except Exception as a:
    print("Exception")
finally:
    p.terminate()
    p.kill()`

> tried with *"os.system()"* and *"signal"* but nothing works for me.

`import os, signal, subprocess, time
try:
    proc1 = subprocess.Popen(args=['python3' 'test.py']).pid
except Exception as a:
    print("Exception")
finally:
    os.kill(proc1, signal.SIGTERM)`